# Django | Panel admin - Si edito un usuario, su password ya no es válido: Encripta de nuevo lo encriptado

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Mediante panel admin, si creo un usuario con su password, todo va bien: El usuario puede iniciar sesión, y cerrar sesión con ese password que le he creado. Pero si entro de nuevo al admin a ese usuario (por ejemplo a editar su nombre), aunque no modifique el password, ya no es válido el password. Creo que **encripta de nuevo el password encriptado**. **¿Cómo puedo hacer que no encripte de nuevo ese password ya encriptado?**

Ejemplo del error:

1- Se crea usuario con su password:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2- Al guardar ha quedado encriptado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3- Si entro en la edición de usuario aunque no modifique nada me cambia el password automáticamente (parece que encripta lo encriptado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**admin.py:**

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'username',
        'password',
        'email',
        'name',
        'last_name',
        'gender'
    )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.password == "pbkdf2" + "*":
            obj.password=obj.password
        else:
            obj.set_password(obj.password) 
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

**model.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M','Masculino'),
        ('F','Femenino'),
        ('O','Otros'),
    )

    
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
    
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name + '' + self.last_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funciona correctamente tras sustituir:

```
if obj.password == "pbkdf2" + "*":
    obj.password=obj.password
```

Por este siguiente código:

```
if obj.password.startswith('pbkdf2'):
    obj.password=obj.password
```

Comment: Y si mi password fuese `pbkdf2hola`?